# Difference between UINT32_C and uint32_t

Tags: c, c99, keil

As far as I know the suffix **t** in *uint32_t* denote **t**ype name but I wonder to know what is the **C** in *UINT32_C* and what is the differences?

Comment: `uint32_t` is a standard [fixed-width integer type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer), and is defined in the `<stdint.h>` system header file. Because it's a standard type, it's portable between platforms.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`UINT32_C` is a macro which defines integer constant of type `uint_least32_t`. For example:

```
UINT32_C(123) // Might expand to 123UL on system where uint_least32_t is unsigned long
              // or just 123U, if uint_least32_t is unsigned int.
```

> #### 7.20.4.1 Macros for minimum-width integer constants
>
> 1. The macro **INT*N*_C(***value***)** shall expand to an integer constant expression
>      corresponding to the type **int_least*N*_t**. The macro **UINT*N*_C(***value***)** shall expand
>      to an integer constant expression corresponding to the type **uint_least*N*_t**. For
>      example, if `uint_least64_t` is a name for the type `unsigned long long int`,
>      then `UINT64_C(0x123)` might expand to the integer constant `0x123ULL`.

It is thus possible that this constant is more than 32 bits on some rare systems.

But if you are on a system where multiple of 8-bits 2's complement types are defined (most modern systems), and `uint32_t` exists, then this creates 32-bit constant.

They all are defined in `stdint.h`, and have been part of the C standard since C99.

Answer (score 8):

`UINT32_C` is a macro for writing a constant of type `uint_least32_t`. Such a constant is suitable e.g. for initializing an `uint32_t` variable. I found for example the following definition in [avr-libc](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdint.html) (this is for the AVR target, just as an example):

```
#define     UINT32_C(value)   __CONCAT(value, UL)
```

So, when you write

```
UINT32_C(25)
```

it's expanded to

```
25UL
```

`UL` is the suffix for an `unsigned long` integer constant. The macro is useful because there is no standard suffix for `uint32_t`, so you can use it without knowing that on your target, `uint32_t` is a `typedef` e.g. for `unsigned long`. With other targets, it will be defined in a different way.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler my bad, I checked the standard, but only searching for the exact identifier. Will update the answer.

Comment: Exactly. It is standard, but  IMO useless

Comment: @PeterJ I tried to explain how it is useful (and thinking about a compiler targeting 8bit µCs, I think it really is), but I indeed never needed something like this before.

Comment: Have you seen anyone using it even on the 8bit platforms.? It is better to write numbers yourself. This makes the code unreadable as well - or maybe less than the "normal" numbers with the suffix

Comment: @PeterJ: Imagine you write code you want to compile an a 64bit *LP64* target as well as on a 8bit target. The 8bit target will have 16bit `int`, so a constant larger than `32767` will not compile without a suffix. But the compiler for LP64 target will compile the constant with `UL` suffix into a 64bit value, not what you want.

Comment: @Felix Palmen code which will compile and run on 8 & 64 bit platforms is not worth touching. 8 bit platforms require a very specific programming as any longer than 8 bits math operations are extremely expensive. Remember - 8 bit targets often do not have even hardware multiplication

Comment: @PeterJ But you know that one design goal of C is to actually *abstract* from the hardware? I agree a situation needing those macros is probably rare (therefore this made-up example), but they are there to achieve exactly this abstraction properly.

Comment: @PeterJ - It is most certainly not useless. Sure you won't use it to initialize a variable, but what about passing an argument to a function chosen by `_Generic` selection? The type of the constant will have great effect.

Comment: @Felix Palmen Maybe C theoreticians never had to program 8 bit targets, and their knowledge is nomen omen theoretical, with no practical value

Comment: @StoryTeller same useless feature. Potential source of very difficult to locate errors. Added probably to be like C++, and say : `you can almost overload in C too`. If you need overloading write in C++

Comment: @PeterJ - I take it you don't like the ISO C committee much.

Comment: @StoryTeller they are not fixing issues, and try to make from C a different language. Useless. Power of is C is its simplicity, not too much abstraction. I actively use both C & C++ and do not see any point of implementing C++ like features in C. _Generic is one of the examples.

Answer (score 3):

These constants are defined something like this:

```
#define UINT32_C(value) (value##UL)
```

You can only put constant values as macro argument, otherwise it wont compile.

```
UINT32_C(10); // compiles

uint32_t x = 10;
UINT32_C(x); // does not compile
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't know about keil, but at least in Linux UINT32_C is a macro to create a uint32_t literal.

And as mentioned by others, uint32_t is a type defined as of C99 in stdint.h.

Answer (score -2):

It is the macro appending the suffix creating the literal  for example `#define UINT32_C(c) c##UL`

Comment: Interesting minus - what is wrong with this answer or maybe it is for example the revenge one

Comment: This answer simple says the macro appends a suffix.  No rational is provided for what suffix, no mention of the resultant type,  no mention that the value needs to be such that it is suffix-able.  Minor: In C, a constant is created, not a _literal_.  In C, its literals (string, compound) can have their address taken - constants not so.

Comment: integer literal is in the common use. I do not think that anyone will be confused by this. See the answer below given by janneb. Another example https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_constants.htm.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_literal.

Comment: @chux and in the formal language theory a literal is a notation for representing a fixed value in source code. The C standard uses term `constant` IMO improperly, not as it is usually understood in the computer science.