# Expression assigned to a wider essential type

Tags: c, lint, misra

I get the following warning from our analysis tool `Composite expression assigned to a wider essential type`
This is the code:

```
uint32_t result;
uint8_t resolution;

result = 1U << resolution;
```

I tried the following:

```
#define SHIFT_BY_ONE (uint8_t)1
result  = SHIFT_BY_ONE << resolution;
```

but that then throws this warning `Shift left of signed quantity (int)`
so I guess I am not understanding the issue correctly. How do I fix this error?

Comment: have you tried `result = (uint32_t)(1U << resolution);`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes and that resulted in an different issue `Impermissible cast of composite expression (wider essential type for the destination)`

Comment: what about `result = 1UL << resolution;` ? what is your platform? have you printed `sizeof(1U)` ?

Comment: Since `1U` is `unsigned int`, which may not be the same as `uint32_t` on some platforms, try `result = ((uint32_t)1) << resolution;`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes that's the one that worked great thanks

Comment: cool, I turned that to an answer.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight That also works thanks. So is the thought process behind the rule that you must cast the operation to be the same type as the variable result?

Comment: @homeGrown You need to cast the operand to ensure that operation result is of the correct type. You need to be especially careful with `uintN_t`s because there are no numeric suffixes that work for them. It turns out C supplies convenient macros for this purpose.

Comment: I take it you configured Lint to check for MISRA-C:2012 compliance? If so, you should tag your question [tag:MISRA]. The warning sounds a whole lot like a MISRA violation.

Comment: At the heart of this problem is a lack of understanding (or a misunderstanding) of the behaviour of the C shift operator... this is not unreasonable, as the C standard is illogical - which is the basis of the MISRA C rule:  Left shifting a **uint8_t** results in **signed int**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This sounds as if you are running a MISRA-C:2012 checker. *Essential type* and *composite expression* are terms from MISRA-C, not from the C standard.

In order to understand anything at all from this warning, you have to study the meaning of essential type (MISRA-C:2012 8.10) and composite expression (MISRA-C:2012 8.10.3).

As for the reason for the warning, it is rule 10.6:

> The value of a composite expression shall not be assigned to an object with wider essential type.

If we ignore the meaning of all these terms, what the rule boils down to is that if you have an operation with 2 operands of a smaller type, the result should not get assigned to a variable of larger type than those operands.

This is to prevent code like this:

```
uint16_t a = 40000;
uint16_t b = 40000;
uint32_t result = a + b;
```

On a 16 bit system, the operands `a` and `b` will not get promoted, so the actual operation will get carried out on 16 bit type - and there will be an unsigned wrap-around (or overflow in case of signed variables).

Confused programmers that don't understand how implicit type promotions work in C might think that the above operation gets carried out on `uint32_t` just because the result is stored in such a type. But this is not correct, the left-hand side of the assignment operator has nothing to do with the sub-expression `a + b` what-so-ever. Which type that gets used in sub-expressions is entirely determined by operator precedence, and `=` has lower precedence than `+`.

Apparently MISRA-C believes that such misunderstandings are common, which is the rationale for this rule.

As for how to fix it, it is easy:

```
result = (uint32_t)1U << resolution;
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed response and explaining the rational behind the rule.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because `1U` does not match `uint32_t` type. Use [`UINT32_C(...)` macro](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45453583/335858) to ensure type compatibility:

```
result = UINT32_C(1) << resolution;
```

Comment: The UINT32_C macro is actually problematic to use with MISRA-C - which this is. Because MISRA-C does not regard `UINT32_C(1)` as an integer constant, it only regards `1` as one and it demands that all integer constants must have a `1U` suffix. But if you would write `UINT32_C(1U)`, the compiler will go bananas. And to be picky `UINT32_C` actually gives a type of `uint_least32_t` and not `uint32_t`. A better solution would be to use `(uint32_t)1U`.

Answer (score 1):

On your system `1U` is probably 16-bit unsigned (which explains the "wider type" when trying to assign to 32-bit unsigned).

In that case, I would use the `long` suffix for the literal:

```
result = 1UL << resolution;
```

(some comments suggest `((uint32_t)1U) << resolution` which would be the most portable way after all)

Comment: `((uint32_t)1) << resolution` indeed is better.  `[unsigned] long` is 64 bits in the LP64 data model used on most Unix/Linux systems.

Comment: To be MISRA compliant (the question is about MISRA-C), use `(uint32_t)1U`.

Answer (score 0):

`1U` may be narrower (16-bit) than `uint32_t` and therefore "Composite expression assigned to a wider essential type".  A shift of a 16-bit `unsigned` by 20 does not make 0x100000,

```
uint32_t result;
uint8_t resolution;
result = 1U << resolution; // Potential 16-bit assignment to a 32-bit type.
```

The narrow-ness of `resolution` is not an issue here.

---

> How do I fix this error?

I prefer to avoid casting when able and offer 2 alternatives.  Both effectively first make a `1` of the destination type without casting.  The compiler will certainly emit optimized code.

```
result = 1u;
result <<= resolution;
// or 
result = (result*0u + 1u) << resolution;
```

Comment: The error is a MISRA error though, so non-compliant code won't solve anything. The compound assignment is ok for MISRA but not the second alternative. Plus, you need to use `U` suffix on all integer constants, regardless of how wide `int` happens to be.

Comment: @Lundin Concerning appending `U`, would `uint16_t a = 40000;` and/or `result = 1;` generate a MISRA warning/error?

Comment: Yes it would, MISRA is rather rigid when it comes to integer constants.